# Open TCP/IPv4 properties with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following Autohotkey mapping to attempt to open the Open TCP/IPv4 properties:

```
#w::
    Run ::{7007acc7-3202-11d1-aad2-00805fc1270e},, max
    WinWaitActive, Network Connections
    Send {Space}w{AppsKey}
    Sleep 250
    Send {Down 9}{Enter}
    WinWaitActive, Wi-Fi Fijo Properties
    ; FIXME: Move down to Ip4/ try to move someway here
    SendInput {Down 10}
    Return
```

However, as it can be seen in the Gif, when I press `WinKey + w` the `SendInput {Down 10}` command doesn't work and the the cursor stays highlighting the first entry `Client for Microsot Networks`). How can this be fixed?

**EDIT:** Updating autohotkey to the latest version seems to have fixed my problem.

[image]

Comment: `Send` vs `SendInput`?

Comment: @meatspace I tried it with `Send` and it didn't work.

Comment: @petobens what are you trying to do?)

Comment: @STTR I want to access the TCP/IPv4 properties window/dialog-box.

Comment: @petobens, I re-created your script and I used `Send {Down 7}`, worked fine for me and it opened my IPv4 Properties. What does Window Spy show when you run the script?

Comment: @petobens netsh, ipconfig, wmic?

Comment: @paradd0x It eventually shows `Wi-Fi Fijo Properties  ahk_class #32770`.

Comment: @STTR I know about netsh and ipconfig. I was wondering how to do this with autohotkey.

Comment: @petobens But what you do - is unreliable. If this is to demonstrate, then there are powerpoint ...

Comment: @paradd0x After seeing your comment I've update to the latest version `1.1.19.02` and everything works just fine. If you want you can post and answer for me to accept. Thanks

Comment: @petobens it would be good if you could post your fix as an answer rather than an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  For EXE created, I right-clicked and Run As Admin

#SingleInstance force

;; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/62277-is-there-a-simpler-way/
;;   PLUS  [Open TCP/IPv4 properties with Autohotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/870125/open-tcp-ipv4-properties-with-autohotkey)

Run ::{7007acc7-3202-11d1-aad2-00805fc1270e},,

;; max

sleep, 1000  ; 1.0 sec

;; mimics a right click on NIC icon - which at the end, 8 lines down, is Properties

Send {Space}w{AppsKey}

sleep, 500

Send {Down 8}{Enter}

sleep, 3500

;; move down to IPv4 line - for me it was 4 lines down ; for others, it maybe different

Send {Down 4}

; click the 'Properties' button, either method should work - using ControlClick ; but they both didn't
; -- correct control name (classNN - ie Button#) or correct control Text (&Pro&perties) are Important ; from WINDOW SPY

; ControlClick, Button4 , IPv4 Properties ;; this Button name didnt work for me

;; ControlClick, &P&roperties , IPv4 Properties ;; this control TEXT name didnt work for me

SendInput {TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}

exitapp

Comment: Use the formatting options in the post editor to make your code and answer more clear.